# Is there a faster way to compare two Int arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, performance

I have two integer array each of **same size say n** ( n is variable, so I can have two arrays of size say 4 or 5 or 6 etc ) and the range of values that each digit can take is in the range of **0-9**.
Example

```
Integer[] one = {1,9,3,4} 
Integer[] two = {1,1,9,3}
```

Now, I want to compare array one & two such that 
**1)** I can get the count of numbers of elements which are same and at the same position.
**2)** I can get the count of number which are same but not at the same position .

The approach I have taken is

**For (1)** Iterate through array one and for each index i check `one[i] == two[i]`. - simple .

**For (2)** Iterate over both the arrays and for `i != j` see if the elements are same , if same mark them with -1 to avoid future conflicts.

```
for(int i =0;i<one.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<two.length;j++){
        if(i != j && one[i] != -1 && two[j] !=-1)){
            if(one[i] == two[j]){
                whiteCount++
                one[i] = -1;
                two[j] = -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Question** : Now I want to know if there is a faster way to do the same thing ? Esp. calculating the **(2)nd part** of the problem. 
This is a basic comparison method to get black and white pegs calculation for [Mastermind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29) board game .
Thanks 
Shakti

**UPDATE 1:** 
1) Rudi's suggestion changed Integer[] to int[]

2) Used Dave Challis's solution 
Change in performance 
for 7776 X 7776 calculations

```
OLD 46950 ms
NEW 42887 ms
```

Comment: @lpratlong OP is also asking to get numbers in the same position.

Comment: @Ipratlong - I dont' think so

Comment: Ok. I remove flag. Sorry for that.

Comment: Are you after [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)?

Comment: Is your goal only getting true/false for comparison of the two arrays?

Comment: You could use `int` instead of `Integer` which would improve performance esp for larger arrays.

Comment: You now have n^2 complexity. What is you sort them first and then run once checking both. 2 * nlog n + n to run over it. This will make it fast with big n's not so sure bout the smaller examples

Comment: Yes, use maps and do a single scan per array!

Comment: This is a basic comparison method to get count of black and white pegs for mastermind game . Updated the question

Comment: What about multiple matches? How do you expect to handle those. e.g. `Integer[] one = {1,9,2,1};` and `Integer[] two = {6,1,7,4};`. How many matches do you expect here? 1 or 2 for your **2)** case?

Comment: @Eypros andwer (0,1) -  0 exact matches and 1 match at a different location. Once a match is found it is updated to -1 so u can't use it again.

Comment: BTW, I'd also recommend using visualvm or similar to profile your code, and find out where most of the time is actually taken, it should give you some hints as to which bits of code to spend time on optimising.

Comment: @Shakti, So did you find a proper solution?

Answer (score 5):

Although this probably isn't exactly what your looking for, we could reduce the number of operations significantly with a very simple change.

From

```
Integer[] one = {1,9,3,4} 
Integer[] two = {1,1,9,3}
```

to

```
int[] one = {1,9,3,4} 
int[] two = {1,1,9,3}
```

This will speed up the process by a small amount, but not by optimizing the sorting/searching logic itself. All we're doing there is removing the auto-boxing and auto-unboxing operations. If however your doing this on a very large scale then this can make a substantial difference.

Answer (score 3):

To get the count of the number of number which are the same, but at different positions, you can do this.

```
public static long[] encode(int... nums) {
    long[] ret = new long[nums.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        ret[i] = ((long) nums << 32) + i;
    }
    Arrays.sort(ret);
}

// encode both arrays and do a merge sort, skipping matches which have the same index.
```

This is an O(n log N) operation.

---

You could move the `one[i] != -1` check out so it can skip that value.

```
int[] one = {1,9,3,4}; // Using int is faster and clearer.
int[] two = {1,1,9,3};

for (int i = 0; i < one.length; i++){
    if (one[i] == -1) continue;
    for (int j = 0; j < two.length; j++){
        if (one[i] == two[j] && i != j && two[j] != -1) {
            whiteCount++
            one[i] = -1;
            two[j] = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Putting the `one[i] == two[j]` first improves performance because it will usually be false so the other things don't need to be checked.

Comment: +1 for strategic use of continue to reduce operations.

Comment: just rename guessStatus to one and secretStatus to two. incorrect copy paste from my side.

Comment: @Shakti that changes the problem.  Can we drop the `i != j` because then you have an O(N log N) problem?

Comment: actually i != j is the part for which I want to fine tune this method

Comment: @Shakti You can still do, it but it's a bit more complicated.  You can do a merge sort, checking the original index.

Answer (score 3):

The solution below is O(2N), doesn't use any additional libraries, and doesn't modify the initial arrays.

It loops through both arrays once to get a count of integers at the same position. While it does this, it builds up a count of each number in the 2nd array (and stores in the `counts` array).

It then loops through the first array again, getting the total number of times each number was found in the 2nd array:

```
final Integer[] one = {1,9,3,4};
final Integer[] two = {1,1,9,3};

int samePositionCount = 0;
int sameNumberCount = 0;

// tracks number of times an int is in the 2nd array
final Integer[] counts = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

for (int i = 0; i < one.length; i++) {
    if (one[i].equals(two[i])) {
        samePositionCount++;
        counts[one[i]] = -1; // mark as seen in same position count
    } else if (counts[two[i]] != -1) {
        counts[two[i]]++;
    }
}

for (int i : one) {
    if (counts[i] > 0) {
        sameNumberCount += counts[i];
        counts[i] = 0; // avoid adding twice
    }
}

System.out.println(samePositionCount + " " + sameNumberCount);
```

Prints:

```
1 2
```

Comment: The original post says that each integer can take the range 0-9, so I used a fixed sized array here. If that wasn't the case, I'd swap to using a Map<Integer,Integer> of some sort.

Comment: @DaveChallis - Answer should be 1,2 . First index 1 matches in both the numbers and 9,3 both present but at a different location

Comment: @Shakti easy to fix that

Comment: @Shakti ah, sorry, missed the part about not counting matches in the 2nd part if they're already in the first. I'll fix the answer to take that into account.

Comment: @Shakti fixed now, by storing a value of -1 in `counts` if a value is matched at a position.

Comment: O(2n) does not exist, it is simply O(n).

Comment: @NateNeuhaus sure O(N) = O(2N), I was just abusing the notation to try and get additional info through :)

Comment: Abusing notation is not important, what is important is using (or abusing) the notation in a way that actually has meaning. Big O notation is simply used to put an upper bound on the growth of the function with respect to its input size. Since constants do not grow, when you include them in your Big-O analysis you are literally saying "this function grows by this additional amount that does not grow". It's simply a nonsensical statement.

Comment: O(2N) is perfectly valid, it's just equivalent to O(N). Similarly, I don't have an issue with seeing people use e.g. O(N³ + N² + N) to help give some indication as to the parts of code/algorithms that might be involved, even though it would be canonically written as O(N³) (i.e. the upper bound).

Comment: It is perfectly valid according to whom? You? It is meaningless, and all who come across your post should be duly warned that providing such a answer in a tech interview will only show the interviewer that you do not understand complexity theory.

Comment: According to the definition of big O. O(2N) = O(3N+1) = O(N), which is why it's canonical to write O(N). I'm not arguing that O(2N) is faster/slower than O(N). Some discussions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777714/which-algorithm-is-faster-on-or-o2n , Quora (https://www.quora.com/In-big-O-notations-why-O-2n-is-equal-to-O-n) etc.

Comment: Sigh. You misunderstand, young Padawan. O(2n) is equivalent O(n) in the same way that "and and" is logically equivalent to just saying "and", however that does not mean that it makes any sense to use it. The whole point of Big-O notation is to describe the GROWTH of a function, this is why adding non-growing constants is not more precise, but rather less credible in displaying your understanding of the fundamentals. This is why no scholarly resources ever tell you to write O(2n), and only the goofballs on the internet that lack education on the subject do. Please do not perpetuate ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the existing utility methods for comparing the aaarays. They are definitely faster. You can check the implemetation of "equals" method and confirm.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int inarr1[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int inarr2[] = {1, 2, 3};
    Object[] arr1 = {inarr1};
    Object[] arr2 = {inarr2};
    if (Arrays.deepEquals(arr1, arr2))
        System.out.println("Same");
    else
        System.out.println("Not same");
   }
```

}

Comment: This doesn't do most of what the original code does.

Comment: I think he wants to compare each value of the arrays.